# How can I include my images in a cocos2d-x .exe on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio, exe, cocos2d-x

I have successfully built my cocos2d-x project on iOS and OS X, and on Windows in VS2012 in debug mode.

However, upon building it for release, it crashes due to the images not being present. This can be fixed by putting the resource directory in the same directory as the .exe file.

However, I would prefer for the .exe to be self-contained, including all of the resources, similar to a .app file on OS X. I assume this is possible somehow, but I don't know how to configure VS to include the images.

Is this possible? How do I go about this?

Comment: Windows has no standard mechanism similar to OS X packages/bundles. There are lots of possible solutions, like zipping all resource files or your own "PAK" file format, but including all assets in an EXE file though possible is not a good idea. You'll notice very, very few games do so and only when they use small amounts of data.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  The OS X bundle method sure feels better to me.  So what is the standard way of distributing Cocos2d-x applications for Windows?  Are the .exe and Resource directories generally just zipped up together?

Comment: Yup, either that or an installer software creates an install package which can run additional tasks ie download updates and drivers, install directx, modify system settings, etc.

Comment: Well, despite not being what I had hoped, I suppose that is the answer.  If you post the above as an answer I will accept it.